# Issue with XAML Slider control

Tags: xaml, slider

I have the value of a slider control bound to a textblock. For some reason it works erratically. For example if I move the thumb slowly I get the right increments, but when I move it fast, It just shows some random stuff.

And here is my value changed event in C#:

```
private void sliderShiftStart_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sliderShiftStart.Value > counter)
        {
            time = time.AddMinutes(30);
            tbTimeDispPopup.Text = string.Format("{0:t}", time);
        }
        else
        {
            time = time.AddMinutes(-30);
            tbTimeDispPopup.Text = string.Format("{0:t}", time);
        }
        counter = Convert.ToInt32(sliderShiftStart.Value);
    }
```

`counter` is a double type variable,

`time` is a DateTime variable,

and `tbTimeDispPopup` is a textblock.

The tracking works fine when I don't do time calculations. I am trying to make time as slider values means the slider minimum is going to be 12:00 AM and the slider maximum is going to be 12:00 AM the next day.

Here is the link to my project, if somebody could have a look at it.
[Project Link](http://1drv.ms/1FaRvZI)

Please advise.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

i've looked on your project, and if i correctly understand, you want to bind textbox text be bound to slider value. To do this i would suggest you the following : bind textbox text to slider value, set min max as you need, and use converter to properly display the DateTime as below.

```
  <Grid Background="DarkSlateGray">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TbTimeDispPopup"
               Grid.Row="0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="30"
               Text="{Binding ElementName=SliderShiftStart, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource ValueToHoursConverter}}"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <Slider x:Name="SliderShiftStart"
            Grid.Row="1"
            MinHeight="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
            Maximum="48"
            TickFrequency="1"/>
</Grid>
```

and here is the converter:

```
public class ValueToHoursConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object result = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        if (value is double)
        {
            result = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours((double)value/2d);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nazar. Somewhere in my mind I knew that a converter would do the needful, but being a newbie< I was finding it hard on where to start with implementing a converter. Was looking onto some code snippets,

Comment: Oh my god, works like a charm. Really appreciate Nazar.

Comment: Hey Nazar: Could you also tell me what was wrong with my setup?

Comment: Hi Nazar, what is the 2d that you are dividing the double value with?

Comment: Don't sure about your setup. Regarding 2d. I divide by 2 because set max value 48, so 1 tick of slider would represent 30 mins after dividing. If you need more details you can set another max and use another divider

Comment: Thanks Nazar for the explanation. Really appreciate it. What is the 'd' for?

Comment: d = double, 2d equal to 2.0